# Update Multiple Objects in Nested Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, lodash

I have an array of multi dimensional objects:

```
var arr = [
  {
    id: '10c',
    name: 'item 1'
    children: [
      {id: '11v', name: 'Item 1 child 1'},
      {id: '12c', name: 'Item 1 child 2'}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '13v',
    name: 'item 2'
    children: [
      {id: '26e', name: 'Item 2 child 1'},
      {id: '7a', name: 'Item 2 child 2'}
    ]
  }
]
```

and another object of data:

```
var array = [
  {id: '12c', name: 'New name 1'},
  {id: '26e', name: 'New name 2'},
  {id: '11v', name: 'New name 3'},
];
```

If I want to update the `name` value of the respective objects in `arr`, based on the `id` value in `array`, how would be the best way of doing that?

`arr` might be more than 2 levels deep, so I would like to be able to do it without having to nest multiple `forEach`

Comment: https://github.com/gaearon/normalizr is a library made for your use case b y normalising nested JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function update(items, id, name) {
    var item;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        item = items[i];
        if (item.id === id) {
            item.name = name;
            return;
        }
        if (item.children) {
             update(item.children, id, name);
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
update(arr, '11v', 'test');
```

Updating by `array`:

```
array.forEach(function (item) {
    update(arr, item.id, item.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive solution and make use of the inherent mutability of Javascript.

First build up a flat map representation of all the objects.

```
function createObjectMap(array) {
  var map = {};

  array.forEach(function(obj) {
    map[obj.id] = obj;

    if(obj.children) {
      Object.assign(map, createObjectMap(obj.children));
    }
  });

  return map;
}
```

Now you've got a map of `id -> object` you can use. They reference the same mutable objects, so you can mutate them in place and know that they'll also update in the original data structure.

```
function update(map, updates) {
  updates.forEach(function(update) {
    map[update.id].name = update.name;
  });
}
```

This conversion to O(1) lookup time means you don't have to write any searching logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use angular $filter to do the same

```
//to get element
function getFiltered(collection, obj){
   var filtered = $filter('filter')(collection, obj, true);
   if(filtered[0])
     return filtered[0]
   if(collection.children)
     return getFiltered(collection.children, obj, true);
}

angular.forEach(array, function(element){
    var filtered = getFiltered(array, { id: element.id })
    if(filtered[0]) filtered.name = element.name;
})
```